# I'm using a map() function using lamda. I have a temperature conversion example using lamda that for some reason executes an empty list

Tags: python

Morning,

I have temperature conversion example below using lamda. The Farhenheit list prints out as expected, but the Celsius list outputs an empty list. Maybe a fresh pair of eyes might help me along. Thanks in advance.

```
temp2 = [39.2, 36.5, 37.3, 37.8]
Farhenheit = map(lambda x: (float(9)/5) * x + 32, temp2)
print(list(Farhenheit))
# > [102.56, 97.7, 99.14, 100.03999999999999]
Celsius = map(lambda x: (float(5)/9) * (x - 32), Farhenheit)
print(list(Celsius))
# > []
```

Comment: The issue here is that the `map` function returns a generator, which is consumed by the `list()` function. Now the generator is empty. Thus applying any operator to it will create a empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `Farhenheit` variable as well as the `Celsius` variable as `lists`, like this:

```py
temp2 = [39.2, 36.5, 37.3, 37.8]
Farhenheit = list(map(lambda x: (float(9)/5) * x + 32, temp2))
print(Farhenheit)
Celsius = list(map(lambda x: (float(5)/9) * (x - 32), Farhenheit))
print(Celsius)
```

The problem here is that the `map()` function returns a generator, not a `list`. Generators are lazy, they generate each item only when needed then don't store it. This makes every element single use.

Thus when you apply the `list` operation inside the `print`, all elements are consumed and removed from the `Farhenheit` map object, then added to the list. Trying to iterate over it a second time will result in an empty sequence, since `map` objects do not store anything.

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved by a explanation why `list` makes a difference

Comment: Thank you @mousetail, I added a few more details to my answer.

Comment: That explanation is incorrect though, no new map object will be created. The map object is consumed when you remove elements from it.

Comment: Thank you once again @mousetail, please check if it's better now.

Comment: I updated your explanation a bit, I hope it's ok

Answer (score 0):

Just convert Fahrenheit to list after map.

```
temp2 = [39.2, 36.5, 37.3, 37.8]

Farhenheit = map(lambda x: (float(9)/5) * x + 32, temp2)

Farhenheit = list(Farhenheit)
print(Farhenheit)

Celsius = map(lambda x: (float(5)/9) * (x - 32), Farhenheit)

print(list(Celsius))

[102.56, 97.7, 99.14, 100.03999999999999]
[39.2, 36.5, 37.300000000000004, 37.8]
```